# Python divide a list of ints on every recurring specific int in list

Tags: python, list, split

How can I change a list like

`[30,20,0,48,20,10,20,0,30]`

to:

`[[30,20],[48,20,10,20],[30]]`

by dividing it everytime there is a `0` in the list? I have tried many ways but they all take up too much lines to make sense (10 lines). I have looked at many list-splitting questions on stack overflow and I cant find anything that works.

EDIT:

I was asking if there was any way to do list.split(0) or something like that, but it appears that the answer is that there is no way to do that. I wanted to know if I can do it in one line or if there is any way I can use a common module. I have already tried doing it in multiple lines, it has worked, but I think it is inconvenient.

EDIT 2:

The code I tried was:

```
list = [30,20,0,48,20,10,20,0,30]  #1, 1 list
newlist = []                       #2, 2 lists
addinglist = []                    #3, 3 lists
for x in list:                     #4
    if x == 0:                     #5
        newlist.append(addinglist) #6
        addinglist = []            #7
    else:                          #8
        addinglist.append(x)       #9 
newlist.append(addinglist)         #10
list = newlist                     #11 lines, 3 lists.
print(addinglist)
```

The code requires 11 lines and 3 lists (one getting modified and the other two are useless).

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Starting a result list, starting a running list, appending to the running list as long as a condition holds true, and appending the current list and starting a new one every time it doesn't is a very common task. Please demonstrate that you've tried something yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
x=[10,20,30,0,4,5,6,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]

output=[]
temp=[]
for i in x:
    if i==0:
        output.append(temp)
        temp=[]
    else:
        temp.append(i)
output.append(temp)
```

Where **output** is:

```
[[10, 20, 30], [4, 5, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1]]
```

The code quite short, but I'm sure there are solutions that are more succinct.

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

As [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175954/python-divide-a-list-of-ints-on-every-recurring-specific-int-in-list#comment73425700_43175954) said:

> Starting a result list, starting a running list, appending to the
>   running list as long as a condition holds true, and appending the
>   current list and starting a new one every time it doesn't is a very
>   common task. Please demonstrate that you've tried something yourself
>   first.

In fact, it is such an easy task, that it is possible to do it in 4 *readeable* lines of Python code:

```
final=[]
for elem in [0]+x:
    if elem == 0: final.append([])
    else: final[-1].append(elem)
```

Where `x` is your list.

---

The purpose of this answer is not to tell you how to do it. But to tell you that with any related code that you could have posted, (and not necessarily working), this answer would have been more accepted.

In conclusion:

- Remember to show your research, just saying to have made the effort does not count, it is not that difficult to copy and paste whatever you have found/made.

Comment: If this is inappropriate for SO, sombody tell me and I'll delete/edit it.

Comment: @SnootierBaBoon Just remember to also put what you tried. If this answer helped you 'sooo much', please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: This can be shortened to `final = []` and `[final.append([]) if elem == 0 else final[-1].append(elem) for elem in [0]+x]` using a list comprehension, and it will be two lines.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if I can do it in one line or if there is any way I
>   can use a common module.

Yes, to both.  You're trying to group data so `groupby` in `itertools` is your friend:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [30, 20, 0, 48, 20, 10, 20, 0, 30]

result = [list(group) for non_zero, group in groupby(data, lambda n: n != 0) if non_zero]

print(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[[30, 20], [48, 20, 10, 20], [30]]
>
```

We're using a key function to bundle the data based on whether it's zero or not.  The `group` variable contains the bundles; the `non_zero` variable (aka `key`) is a boolean indicating if it's a bundle we want.